# the internalformat of Texture

Tags: opengl, graphics

Look at the following OpenGL function:

```
void glTexImage2D(GLenum    target,
                  GLint     level,
                  GLint     internalFormat,
                  GLsizei   width,
                  GLsizei   height,
                  GLint     border,
                  GLenum    format,
                  GLenum    type,
                  const GLvoid * data);
```

I know the parameter format and type describe the format and type of the image data,but I don't understand the prameter **internalFormat**.How should I set its value in my application?

For example,I create a texture like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_LUMINANCE8,size,size,0,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buffer);
```

When I aceess the texture in it in my GLSL shader,it seems that the value that I get is between [0,1].WHy?Shouldn't it between [0,255]?

Part of My shader code is :

```
vec = EntryPoint + delta_dir * texture(noiseTex,EntryPoint.xy * 32).x;
```

Part of my C++ Code :

```
for (int i = 0;i < temp;++i)
    {
        buffer[i] = 255.0 * rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
    }
    glGenTextures(1,&noiseTex);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + activeTexUnit);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,noiseTex);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_LUMINANCE8,size,size,
                            0,GL_LUMINANCE,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,buffer);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: You should post your shader code so we can diagnose the behavior you're describing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `format` and `type` parameters describe the data you are passing to OpenGL as part of a [pixel transfer operation](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Pixel_Transfer). The `internalformat` describes the *[format of the texture](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format)*. You're telling OpenGL that you're giving it takes that looks like X, and OpenGL is to store it in a texture where the data is Y. The `internalformat` is "Y".

The `GL_LUMINANCE8` internal format represents a *normalized* unsigned integer format. This means that the data is conceptually floating-point, but stored in a normalized integer form as a means of compression.

For that matter, the `format` of `GL_LUMINANCE` says that you're *passing* either floating-point data or normalized integer data (the `type` says that it's normalized integer data). Of course, since there's no `GL_LUMINANCE_INTEGER` (which is how you say that you're passing *integer* data, to be used with integer internal formats), you can't really use luminance data like this.

Use `GL_RED_INTEGER` for the format and `GL_R8UI` for the internal format if you really want 8-bit unsigned *integers* in your texture. Note that integer texture support requires OpenGL 3.x-class hardware.

That being said, you ***cannot*** use `sampler2D` with an integer texture. If you are using a texture that uses an unsigned integer texture format, you ***must*** use `usampler2D`.

Comment: Specifying (sized) internal format is just a hint to GL. GL is only required to have one sized internal format each base internal format thus and may convert the input in any way it wants. LUMINANCE8 may be represented internally by LUMINANCE4. The standard itself does not prohibit it though.

Comment: @Andreas: There are a number of required internal formats which are not allowed to be "just a hint".

Comment: Reading OpenGL 1.3 specification I find no SIZE requirement for the internal formats. Did that change in later versions? Have I misinterpreted the standard?

Comment: @Andreas: "*Did that change in later versions?*" Yes. You should probably look at OpenGL versions that were written in the last *decade*. There have been required versions since GL 3.0.

Comment: Haha you are right. I'm in military product development where a decade behind is actually not that bad. I'll take a peek. Considering the backwards compatibilty phantom looming over OpenGL 3.0+ I just guessed nothing had changed. Besides the question (nor the answer) declares which version we are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

How the value is stored internally is not necessarily relevant to how you would access it in GLSL.  Using normalised colour values (0-1) is much easier in practice.  Is there some reason you want to manipulate pixel values in your pixel shaders in the range of (0-255)?

Comment: How could I use normalised color values(0-1) bye setting the parameters and How to manipulate pixel values in my pixel shaders in the range of 0-255 by setting the parameters?Thanks~

Comment: @XiaJun: By specification the value range for integer based image formats is always normalized to the range [0,1]. Only for floating point internal format the values are passed through. However not all OpenGL implementations do support float textures. Why do you need values [0,255] at all? It's just a multiplicative factor of 255 to be applied.