# Prevent DataTexture value normalization in THREE

Tags: three.js

In THREE you can specify a DataTexture with a given data type and format. My shader pipeline **normalizes** the raw values based on a few user-controlled uniforms.

In the case of a Float32Array, it is very simple:

```
data = new Float32Array(...)
texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, columns, rows, THREE.LuminanceFormat, THREE.FloatType)
```

And, in the shader, the swizzled values have **non-normalized** values. However, if I use:

```
data = new Uint8Array(...)
texture = new THREE.DataTexture(data, columns, rows, THREE.LuminanceFormat, THREE.UnsignedByteType);
```

Then the texture is normalized between 0.0 and 1.0 as an input to the pipeline. Not what I was expecting. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Here is an example jsfiddle demonstrating a quick test of what is unexpected (at least for me): http://jsfiddle.net/VsWb9/3796/

three.js r.71

Comment: I believe this is not possible at the moment based on the reply and assumption of this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041830/the-internalformat-of-texture that regards similar issue, but not under WebGL. I need to look into it more before posting an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, this is not currently possible in WebGL. It requires the use of **GL_RED_INTEGER** and the unsupported **usampler2d**.

This comment from [the internalformat of Texture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041830/the-internalformat-of-texture) also describes the issue in GL for the internal formats.

> For that matter, the format of GL_LUMINANCE says that you're passing
>   either floating-point data or normalized integer data (the type says
>   that it's normalized integer data). Of course, since there's no
>   GL_LUMINANCE_INTEGER (which is how you say that you're passing integer
>   data, to be used with integer internal formats), you can't really use
>   luminance data like this.
>
> Use GL_RED_INTEGER for the format and GL_R8UI for the internal format
>   if you really want 8-bit unsigned integers in your texture. Note that
>   integer texture support requires OpenGL 3.x-class hardware.
>
> That being said, you cannot use sampler2D with an integer texture. If
>   you are using a texture that uses an unsigned integer texture format,
>   you must use usampler2D.