# Create texture from Array THREE.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, terrain

I'm working on a terrain generator, but I can't seen to figure out how to do the colors. I want to be able to generate an image that will take up my whole PlaneGeometry. My question is how can I create a single image that will cover the entire PlaneGeometry (with no wrapping) based off my height map? I can think of one way, but I'm not sure it would fully cover the PlaneGeometry and it would be very inefficient. I'd draw it in a two-dimensional view with colors on a canvas. I'd then convert the canvas to the texture Is that the best/only way?

UPDATE: Using DataTexture, I got some errors. I have absolutely no idea where I went wrong. Here's the error I got:
`WebGL: drawElements: texture bound to texture unit 0 is not renderable. It maybe non-power-of-2 and have incompatible texture filtering or is not 'texture complete'. Or the texture is Float or Half Float type with linear filtering while OES_float_linear or OES_half_float_linear extension is not enabled.`
Both the DataTexture and the PlaneGeometry have a size of 512^2. What can I do to fix this?

Here's some of the code I use:

EDIT: I fixed it. Here's the working code I used.

```
function genDataTexture(){
    //Set the size.
    var dataMap = new Uint8Array(1 << (Math.floor(Math.log(map.length * map[0].length * 4) / Math.log(2))));
        /* ... */
        //Set the r,g,b for each pixel, color determined above
            dataMap[count++] = color.r;
            dataMap[count++] = color.g;
            dataMap[count++] = color.b;
            dataMap[count++] = 255;
        }
    var texture = new THREE.DataTexture(dataMap, map.length, map[0].length, THREE.RGBAFormat);
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    return texture;
}
/* ... */
//Create the material
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: genDataTexture()});
//Here, I mesh it and add it to scene. I don't change anything after this.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optimal way, if the data is already in your Javascript code, is to use a `DataTexture` -- see https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/DataTexture for the general docs, or look at `THREE.ImageUtils.generateDataTexture()` for a fairly-handy way to make them. http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras/ImageUtils

Comment: I'm getting some errors. I added them in the question. Can you show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: `THREE.ImageUtils.generateDataTexture()` has been removed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47782274/what-happened-to-three-imageutils