# What happened to THREE.ImageUtils?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Working on updating some old javascript three.js code on textures. 
Specifically the second line below.

```
var groundColor = new THREE.Color(0xd2ddef);
var groundTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils().generateDataTexture(1, 1, groundColor); // this line
var groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, specular: 0x111111, map: groundTexture });

var groundTexture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('img/ground.jpg', undefined, function() { groundMaterial.map = groundTexture });
groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
groundTexture.repeat.set(25, 25);
groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;
```

What new method/constructor/etc has three.js replaced THREE.ImageUtils().generateDataTexture?

Comment: Please write which versions you are updating to and from.

Answer (score 3):

`generateDataTexture` was removed from three.js core in r73. However [here is the commit where it was removed](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/1ac876f1c60c202459a02e48932faad83fc76c19) where you can find the simple `generateDataTexture` function. You could just copy and paste it into your code and call it as needed. [r88]

Comment: please also write what versions of three.js are you updating from and to

Comment: @pailhead Think you meant to direct this at ezweizig

Comment: oops yes, my phone is too small :(, still though, wouldnt hurt to add it to the answer, it's kinda happening in some answers as an unofficial convention :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone, I was able to replace `ImageUtils.generateDataTexture` with `THREE.DataTexture`, using the color as the data.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/textures/DataTexture